# Javascript - Function not returning array, logs to console just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My code is supposed to accept a list of ID's, this list matches the scarlet-id on certain elements. My code then builds up an array with the elements attributes and the values. This is where the issues set in, when I console.log the array, it outputs in Chrome's console just fine.

[image: Output to console]

But when I pass the array to JSON.stringify, or try to use it in an AJAX request, none of the data gets transmitted. (below is the output from JSON.stringify)

[image: JSON.stringify output]

Here's my code.

```
function getScarletIDInfo(scarletIDs)
{

    var scarletIDinfo = new Array();    

    for (var i = 0; i < scarletIDs.length; i++) 
    {

        scarletIDinfo[scarletIDs[i]] = new Array();

        $($(getSpecificSelector(scarletIDs[i]))[0].attributes).each(function() 
        {

            scarletIDinfo[scarletIDs[i]][this.nodeName] = this.nodeValue;

        });

    };

    console.log(scarletIDinfo);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(scarletIDinfo));

    return scarletIDinfo;

}

function getSpecificSelector(scarletID)
{

    return "*[scarlet-id=" + scarletID + "]";

}
```

I'd be very grateful if somebody could point out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an object, not an array.

```
var scarletIDingo = {};
// ...
    scarletIDinfo[scarletIDs[i]] = {};
// ...
```